# api redirection in nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am making mock authentication in node js using passport, jwt. I have created successfully api. I am using handlebars for templating.

Suppose when user post credential to login(post), the api should verify the user and return json content. I stuck here how I redirect to another page after redirection.I don't want this in my api.

My code is this:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

        if (req.body.name == '' || req.body.password == '') {
              res.status(401).send('Please fill all fields')
        } else {
            let name = req.body.name;
            // let password = req.body.password;
            // usually this would be a database call:
            let user = users[_.findIndex(users, {
                name: name
            })];
            if (user === undefined) {
                  res.status(401).send('User not defined')

            } else {
                if (user.password === req.body.password) {
                    let payload = {
                        id: user.id
                    };
                    let token = jwt.sign(payload, config.jwtSecret);
                        res.json({message: "ok", token: token});

                } else {
                      res.status(401).send('Password did not match')

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

My doubt is this from this api How can I redirect to next page if user is authenticated. I can not change code in this api as I am using this api for testing also.

Comment: You can use [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) with  [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/)

Comment: can u give any good example or refrence??

Comment: Ok I let references on before comment

Comment: What about front end redirect after user is authenticated ?

Comment: I didnt get what u want to say??

Answer (score 0):

I'm still kinda new to Node.js but I believe to redirect you can use

`res.redirect("/pageyouwant");`

Maybe in the bracket where the user gets authenticated, you can use the code I wrote above.

Btw, maybe try my code in that place

```
if (user.password === req.body.password) {
      let payload = {
            id: user.id
      };
      let token = jwt.sign(payload, config.jwtSecret);
      res.json({message: "ok", token: token});

      res.redirect("/pageyouwant"); // <-- This one right here
 }
```

Hope I could helped you.

Comment: No mate..I cant set redirect field in my api...api is for general purpose